# Mac OS X dual boot with encrypted Ubuntu LVM

Tags: dual-boot, encryption, lvm

I'd like to Setup my Mac Book Pro with dual Boot Ubuntu 13.04 & OS X Mountain Lion.
Because the machine contains corporate data, I need to encrypt both Operating Systems.

With Mac I can use FileVault. For Ubuntu I need an encrypted LVM (am I right?).

I can't setup Ubuntu with LVM because it wipes my entire disk and can only use the whole disk to init LVM. I need both aside, so this doesn't work for me.

- Is there any way to encrypt the Ubuntu partition if there is no LVM?
- Can i setup LVM and not use the entire disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never done anything like this but I would backup Mac OS X and install Ubuntu with encryption and LVM which is an option on the installer which will also wipe the disk. Then you can resize the encrypted Ubuntu (which you can look up how to do) so you have space to install Mac OS X. Then restart your Mac and hold alt on boot. Then you connect to internet. Then you'll see an internet recovery option, which you click and use restore from backup. Then you should have a dualboot. I think.

Answer (score 1):

Why dual boot? Dual booting is rather antiquated, imo. By using a vm you can run both systems at the same time. This is how I have my macbook configured and it works a charm. Just install the mac os encrypted, install vmware fusion, and install ubuntu in a vm. Because the drive is encrypted beneath the vm, you can have access to both systems soon as you log into the mac.